# Java reorganize lists

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list I read in from a text file that looks something like this:

> apples
>   oranges
>   NEXT
>   shirt
>   pants
>   gloves
>   socks
>   NEXT
>   cube
>   square
>   triangle
>   NEXT
>   ect...

This repeates many many many times for all sorts of different things. I was wondering how I would read this file in, then write it back to a text file in a different random order, but still in their categories. For example the shapes (aka cube, square, triangle) might be first followed by a *"NEXT"* then a different category of things.

So far I have loaded the file and put everything into one string, have debated using a `split` command on the *"NEXT"* to separate the categories, just not sure how to really do this.

```
void rearrange() {
    String tempOrder = "";

    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File("./randomFile.txt");
        input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            tempOrder += input.nextLine() + "\n";
        }
        String[] parts = tempOrder.split("NEXT");
        //Not sure how to reorganize the array now randomly
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've loaded the file in it's entirety in one String object, you can split on newline characters to get your individual items into an array. Then you could sort through the array with a for loop checking for NEXT to do something different with each category. You're going to need to show some work and exactly what you are stuck on and what error you are getting to get much more help. People here don't like writing code for what looks like homework.

Comment: You could read up on [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @Kenney Am currently using string split, see code I attached. The problem was arranging the catagories, either in string form or array form.

Comment: Split again, on newline.

Comment: @Kenney Not sure how this would help at all. This would give me the individual items which I do not want. I want catagories (which are representing within the "NEXT". Can you elaborate how splitting again helps?

Comment: So, you read each line, concatenate them and then split them again? And Kenney suggests to split even more? Wow. Lain, you already have each single element of a categories, so store them separately in a suitable collection, like a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Create a new list for each category. Then use [`Collections#shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) to get your random order.

Comment: @Tom Thank you, putting it in collection list class and using the prebuild shuffle works quickly and does exactly what I need, and easily allows me to rewrite to the file also.

Comment: @Lain sorry, I misread; I thought you wanted to shuffle the contents of each `NEXT`-delimited list of categories.

Comment: @Lain You wrote that code in four minutes? Not bad :D. Btw if you have a corrected code which solved this question here, then please write an answer to your question, so future readers with a similar question can see how to do that.

Comment: @Kenney That's what he wants. He want to shuffle the elements of each group, but only in their group. So a cloth like "sock" won't be shuffled into the "shape" group.

Comment: @Lain It would give you the individual items *in each category*: `foreach ( String s: tempOrder.split("NEXT\n") ) { String [] items = s.split("\n"); }`.
@Tom at the time I posted that comment, there was no code posted, and all the info I had was that there was a string holding all file contents, and that this content was split on `NEXT`. Be careful with your assumptions.

Comment: @Kenney You don't need his code to see that reading the whole file into a single String and then using `split` is bad code. But there is no point in fighting about this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a 2-dimensional array (an array of arrays).
Read your file in line by line and have an if statement to catch if the line says "NEXT." If it does say "NEXT", then start writing the words to the next array. You could then randomize the indices of the outer array.

The psuedo-code would look something like this:

```
array[ ][ ];
int category = 0;
int i = 0;
foreach line in file {
  if line == "NEXT" {
    category++;
    i = 0;
    continue;
  }
  array[category][i] = line;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: An array? And how big do you want to make this array to be sure that the whole file with an unknown amount of categories fits in it?

Comment: For the record its currently around ~250thousand items and around 80thousand catagorizes, and is growing every day. Time isnt super important though for sorting and stuff since this program does not need to be done in real time or anything.

Comment: @Tom I wasn't going for explicitness, but rather concept. In Java, the ArrayList class is dynamically sized. You could also use a vector.

Comment: Even with explaining the concept you can avoid naming unsuitable data types ;P.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a **list of lists** instead of arrays to store the values in the file. And use **Collections.shuffle** to randomly reorder each sublist. This would avoid concatenating each input and then split again(which seems redundant).

**Edit:** I would also use LinkedList over ArrayList since the number of input is unknown to avoid frequent resizing of the ArrayList.

```
static void rearrange() {
    List<LinkedList<String>> categoryList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();
    final String NEXT = "NEXT";
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(A.class.getResourceAsStream("randomFile.txt"));
        LinkedList<String> singleCategory = new LinkedList<>();

        String value = "";
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            value = input.nextLine();
            if (value.equals(NEXT)) {
                categoryList.add(singleCategory);
                singleCategory = new LinkedList<>(); // create a new category when the line is NEXT
            } else {
                singleCategory.add(value);
            }
        }

        if (!value.equals(NEXT)) {
            categoryList.add(singleCategory); // don't forget to add the last category
        }

        for (LinkedList<String> category : categoryList) {
            Collections.shuffle(category); // randomly rearrange each category
        }

        for (LinkedList<String> category : categoryList) {
            for (String singleValue : category) {
                System.out.println(singleValue);
            }
            System.out.println(NEXT);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```